# (see the screenshot..edited now)could not insert data into MySQLdb using python-flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I created a db table from terminal, and now i want to insert data to it using following code,sql_insert_reg statement which is used as sql insert command is same as that i use in terminal insert operations but using in python file does not insert data .I am learning use of mysql in flask,here's my code.This code does not give error but does nothing as i expect it to!

```
mysql = MySQL()
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'EmpData'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)

class RegistrationForm(Form):
  username = TextField('Username', [validators.Length(min=4, max=25)])
  password = PasswordField('New Password', [
                         validators.Required(),
                         validators.EqualTo('confirm', message='Passwords must match')])
  confirm = PasswordField('Repeat Password')
  accept_tos = BooleanField('I accept the TOS', [validators.Required()])

@app.route('/register',methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
  form = RegistrationForm(request.form)
  flash('login details')
  session['tmp'] = 43
  if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
    username = form.username.data
    password = form.password.data
    sql_insert_reg = "INSERT INTO User(userName,password) VALUES(%s,%s)"
    #flash(sql_insert_reg)
    conn = mysql.connect()
    cursor = mysql.get_db().cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql_insert_reg,(username,password))
    conn.commit()
return render_template('register.html',form=form)
```

**this is the screenshot i uploaded below..please see the entries useId 2 then goes directly to 6 ..and i got to see this by altering the answer as suggested to me!!can anyone lookout the problem behind the scene![image]**

**Please help me!**

Comment: No, no, and no. Your new year's resolution for this year needs to be to never write SQL using the % operator ever again, not even for a test system. You should get in the habit of using cursor.execute() to build every query, every time, all the time, no exceptions. And then read up on how to manage auth using salted hash values... don't store passwords in plaintext ever again.

Comment: @dylrei okay i will make my code better...thanks...can you help to figure out the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed some code and found that instead of using the above lines of code in mysql i got this magic!

```
import MySQLdb

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","testuser","test123","TESTDB" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = """INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(FIRST_NAME,
     LAST_NAME, AGE, SEX, INCOME)
     VALUES ('Mac', 'Mohan', 20, 'M', 2000)"""

try:
 #  Execute the SQL command
 cursor.execute(sql)
 # Commit your changes in the database
 db.commit()
except:
 # Rollback in case there is any error
 db.rollback()

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what a typical INSERT statement looks like:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1,column2,column3) VALUES (value1,value2,value3);
```

Note that if your first column is auto-incremental (e.g. some sort of index), you can ommit that from the statement and just write it as follows:

```
INSERT INTO User (user_column, pass_column) VALUES ('foo', 'bar');
```

Comment: It doesnt matter using that...mine also works fine!!

Answer (score 0):

So... don't do this:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Table VALUES(NULL,'%s','%s')"%(username,password)+";"
```

Do this instead:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Table (col1, col2) VALUES (%s, %s)"
cursor.execute(sql, (value1, value2))
```

Why? Because that will sanitize your input and you don't end up registering [Bobby Drop Table](http://xkcd.com/327/) as a user.

If doing it that way doesn't do what you expect, please provide more detail on what is happening, what you're expecting and how you know that you don't have what you expect to see.

Comment: it gives me _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError

Answer (score 0):

this could be your problem

```
ursor.execute(sql_insert_reg,(username,password))
```

looks like it should be

```
cursor.execute(sql_insert_reg,(username,password))
```

and if thats not it, i would just use sqlalchemy to generate the sql for you

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker,scoped_session
import sqlalchemy as sa

Model = declarative_base()
engine = sa.create_engine('mysql://DB_USERNAME:DB_PASSWORD@DB_HOST:DB_PORT/DB_NAME')
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
db_session = Session()

class User(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = sq.Column(sq.Integer,primary_key=True)
    username = sq.Column(sq.String(255),nullable=False,unique=True)
    password = sq.Column(sq.Text,nullable=False)
```

then if you want to manipulate the data you can change  this from above

```
username = form.username.data
password = form.password.data
sql_insert_reg = "INSERT INTO User(userName,password) VALUES(%s,%s)"
#flash(sql_insert_reg)
conn = mysql.connect()
cursor = mysql.get_db().cursor()
ursor.execute(sql_insert_reg,(username,password))
conn.commit()
```

to this

```
user = User(username=form.username.data,password=form.password.data)
db_session.add(user)
db_session.commit()
```

Comment: This helped me...but i am still anoyed why my answer is not giving this magic!!I am unable to figure out what the problem is with my code!!anyways if you can suggest some answer without sqlalchemy part..please explain..if not i have to carry this process!!